# How to get around a Possible Loss of Precision Error in java

Tags: java, scaling

I'm working on a scaling system, to scale numbers up 25% and round to the nearest integer, and to do this, I am trying to rely on the loss of precision by transferring a double into an int. Is there any way to get around this? or should I go about it in a different way?

```
public int[] scaleMarks(int[] marks)
{
    double scale = 1.25;
    double temp1;
    int temp2;

    for(int i = 0; i < marks.length; i++)
    {
        temp1 = marks[i] * scale;
        temp2 = marks[i] * scale; //***Loss of precision here***

        if(temp1-temp2>= 0.5)
        {
            temp2++;
        }
        marks[i] = temp2;

    }


    return marks;
}
```

Comment: "trying to rely on loss of precision"..... This seems dangerous.

Comment: Casting a double to an int won't round to the nearest int, it will floor it.

Comment: well i know that it would become the closest integer below the actual value, and i was going to use the difference between the two to establish which way I should round, but I think I just worked it out. by making it 
temp2 = (int)  (marks[i] * scale);
it seems to compile, but I'm currently unable to test it, as my laptop does not allow me to run the compiled file.

Comment: Making it `temp2 = (int) (marks[i] * scale)` just drops the decimal straight up.

Comment: Then I checked for the difference between them in the if statement to establish the rounding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to round the product with [`Math.round`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round-double-) so that it can be casted to an `int` safely.

```
marks[i] = (int) Math.round(marks[i] * scale);
```

Comment: That looks like it will shorten my code quite a bit. I will definitely test it when I have the chance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want round-to-nearest, rather than truncation, you need to use Math.round.

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println((int)0.999999);
    System.out.println(Math.round(0.999999));
  }
}
```

outputs

```
0
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Math.round function to avoid it:

```
(int)Math.round(marks[i] * scale);
```

**EDIT:** You will have to cast it to `int` because if you don't do that the result will be wrong (because `scale` it's a `double`).

I expect it will be helpful for you!